# Where does the Squid proxy stores its cache files?

Tags: cache, squid, http-proxy

Imagine that I have hosted a web server. And to speed up things I have used an http caching proxy called Squid. Where actually squid stores its cache files and how long will it remain there? I am on a Linux system.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution after some googling. First on terminal type

```
grep cache_dir /etc/squid/squid.conf
```

It outputs as

```
cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 100 16 256
```

Where `/var/spool/squid` is the location of your squid cache folder. This directory will contain so many sub-directories into which the cache files are stored.