# Cache proxy to store media

Tags: proxy, browser-cache, squid, http-proxy

I want to set up a caching proxy that will store all the content (i.e. pics, videos, etc...) of the browsers that use the proxy.

I've managed to set up a squid proxy server but couldn't find mp4 files in the cache folder
(used the answer here to find the cache folder: [Where does the Squid proxy stores its cache files?](https://superuser.com/questions/818668/where-does-the-squid-proxy-stores-its-cache-files) )

another issue was that the cache files also store HTTP headers - is there a way to open media files directly from the cache folder?

maybe squid-proxy is not the right tool for the task?

**My Question:**
How can I set-up a proxy that store the entire content it serves and that I can open the cached files from the cache folder?

Actually it's not have to be a proxy solution - browser configuration will also be good if possible...